# Back to the previous activity on back pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have a function which display FileDialog and Intent to use Bluetooth.
But when I press back button, it comes to previous activity, it is visible but not clickable (like screenshot) and I have to press the back button once again.
I tried function `onBackPressed() { finish(); }`, but nothing worked properly.

**MainActivity:**

```
    ...
        if(item == shareMenu) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShareViaBluetoothActivity.class));
        }
...
```

**ShareViaBluetoothActivity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class ShareViaBluetoothActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int DISCOVER_DURATION = 300;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLU = 1;

    private FileDialog fileDialog;

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    private File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "//DIR//");
        fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, mPath);
        fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
            public void fileSelected(File file) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "selected file " + file.toString());
                setFile(file);
                sendViaBluetooth();
            }
        });
        fileDialog.showDialog();
    }

    public void sendViaBluetooth() {

        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(btAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not supported on this device!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            enableBluetooth();
        }
    }

    public void enableBluetooth() {

        Intent discoveryIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);

        discoveryIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, DISCOVER_DURATION);

        startActivityForResult(discoveryIntent, REQUEST_BLU);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == DISCOVER_DURATION && requestCode == REQUEST_BLU) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("*/*");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(file.toString())));
            intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");

            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            if(appsList.size() > 0) {
                String packageName = null;
                String className = null;
                boolean found = false;

                for(ResolveInfo info : appsList) {
                    packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
                    if(packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")) {
                        className = info.activityInfo.name;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth havn't been found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain what exactly mean by `But when I press back button, it comes to previous activity, it is visible but not clickable (like screen) and I have to press the back button once again` ?

Comment: When I start the activity from MainActivity, fileDialog shows up. Then when I want to cancel, I press the "back press button". Then dialog disappear, MainActivity is visible, but not clickable. I mean, I can tap on screen wherever I want and nothing happens. Its like screenshot, like photo. When I press the "back press button" again, then everything is ok.

Comment: Yes, but how to solve it? I tried finish() method, but it does not work.

Comment: back event is consumed by `FileDialog`  and `ShareViaBluetoothActivity` is actually not finished .  finish `ShareViaBluetoothActivity` forcefully in OnDismiss of `FileDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

What you described was not so complete. But I this there are some reasons may result to this, then you can check it.
1. use super.onBackPressed() or give onBackPressed() return can make different
2. please check activity launch mode work.

but you'd better give a more detailed code,then I can help you

Comment: I think, I gave everything. :) In MainActivity I call ShareViaBluetoothActivity, and ShareViaBluetoothActivity code is posted.

Comment: what do you mean by ShareViaBluetoothActivity code is posted?